# Nginx - Muliple redirects using map

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I need to redirect some urls permanently on the same domain.
I'm trying to use `map` directive. I followed some asnwers to similar questions, but they don't work. Here is my setup.
**website.conf**

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
  /businesses/categories/1 /businesses/autobiznes;
  /businesses/categories/7 /businesses/torgovlya;
  /businesses/categories/8 /businesses/apteka;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.website.ru;
  return 301 http://website.ru$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name website.ru;
  charset utf-8;
  keepalive_timeout 5;

  root /srv/www/website_production/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;

  rewrite_log on;

  location ~ ^/businesses/categories {
    if ($new_uri) {
      return 301 $new_uri;
    }
  }
}
```

When I request `http://website.ru/businesses/categories/1`
I should get `http://website.ru/businesses/autobiznes`
but I get `http://www.$server_name.com/businesses/autobiznes`.
What am I doing wrong? And maybe there is a better way to mass redirect?

Comment: Unsure if this is it, but in your location block, I noticed you're 301-ing the `$new_uri` rather than the full URI, e.g. `return 301 http://$server_name$new_uri;` (no slash between b/c you've included it in the `$new_uri` values).  Also, maybe set a default for your map?

Comment: Whats the best way to set `$server_name`?

Comment: You already did with `server_name website.ru;`. [server_name docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) :)

Comment: Same issue after following your suggestions. Maybe there is a problems because I also have redirect from www to non-www? I updated the question. Otherwise I don't have a clue what to do. Any alternatives?

Comment: Is that now the full config?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leemour/d954cac693a40fb68a62 full config